# Oracle SQL Count distinct values in a certain column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query a table with a certain logic and I want to remove the records which have a count of 2 or more distinct values in PERSON_ID column. I cannot find an appropriate window query to achieve this. I already tried using:

```
SELECT 
CUSTOMER_ID, PERSON_ID, CODE,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_iD, PERSON_ID ORDER BY PERSON_ID ASC) AS NR 
FROM TBL_1;
```

But I get the following result:

[image]

I want to achieve the result below, which counts the distinct values within PERSON_ID column based on a certain CUSTOMER_ID. In my case Customer "444333" would be a record which I want to remove because it has 2 distinct Person_Id's

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the distinct count on each row, then use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       count(distinct person_id) over (partition by customer_id)
from t;
```

Oracle *does* support `distinct` in window functions.

Answer (score 2):

here is what you need:

```
SELECT 
customer_id, count(distinct PERSON_ID) distinct_person_count
FROM TBL_1
group by customer_id
```

and if you want to show it for eahc row , you can join it again with the table :

```
select * from TBL_1 t
join (
     select customer_id, count(distinct PERSON_ID) distinct_person_count
     from TBL_1
     group by customer_id
) tt
on t.customer_id = tt.customer_id
```

note: you can't have distinct within window functions